# Inline children of an element, if there's only one elements of that type

Tags: xml, xsd, xmlschema

Suppose I want to model a `<Product>`. A product can either have variants (e.g. a T-shirt that comes in different colours), or have a single variant, like a sweater that only comes in one colour.

I want to make a schema that allows for both of these syntaxes to be valid:

```
<MyXMLDoc>

<Product>
  <Variants>  
    <Variant>
      <Name>Red T-Shirt</Name>
      <Description>A red t-shirt</Description>
    </Variant>

    <Variant>
      <Name>Green T-Shirt</Name>
      <Description>A green t-shirt</Description>
    </Variant>

    <Variant>
      <Name>Blue T-Shirt</Name>
      <Description>A blue t-shirt</Description>
    </Variant>

  </Variants>
</Product>

<Product>
  <Name>Black sweater</Name>
  <Description>A plain ol' black sweater</Description>
</Product>

</MyXMLDoc>
```

The closest I could get was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="MyXMLDoc">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Product"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Product">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element ref="Variant"/>
                <xs:element ref="Variants"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Variants">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Variant"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Variant">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Name"/>
                <xs:element ref="Description"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

The `xs:choice` between a `<Variant>` or `<Variants>` allows me to get rid of the `<Variants>` level of nesting, but the `<Name>` and `<Description>` still need to be parented under a single `<Variant>`.

Is there a way to tell an XML-schema to expect either an element (`<Variant>`), or the in-lined members of an element (the `<Name>`, `<Description>` from within a `<Variant>`, without needing to actually be wrapped in a `<Variant>`)?
Notice that the `<Name>` and `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are aiming at:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="MyXMLDoc">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Product"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Product">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:group ref="VariantGroup"/>
                <xs:element ref="Variant"  maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Variant">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:group ref="variantGroup"/> 
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:group name="VariantGroup">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>

</xs:schema>
```

I have removed the `<Variants>` level because your comments seem to indicate that you want to avoid it - although your XML example does include it.

Although your suggested XML can be described using XML Schema, I think it would be simpler to represent the single-variant product like this:

```
<Product>
  <Variant>
    <Name>Black sweater</Name>
    <Description>A plain ol' black sweater</Description>
  </Variant>
</Product>
```

That would make the XML Schema much simpler - just set minOccurs=1 on the Variant element.

Comment: Ah, `xs:group` is precisely what I was looking for, thanks! You're right that the schema is a little more complex, but the payload size reduction and simplicity is worth it in my use-case.

Comment: Hey Kim, do you know if it's conventional to use a `xs:choice` within an `xs:group`, as a way of making a named union of several complex types? E.g. I made a named group that I refer to as `OneOrMoreImages` that can model both `<Images><Image/><Image/><Image/></Images>` and `<Image/>`

Comment: It's not wrong, but I would hesitate to call it 'conventional' because almost everybody handles your use case using a variable-length array. I know you're trying to minimise document size, but XML is a strange choice if that is a major concern!

Comment: My aim for brevity is more about simplifying simple cases (one image, one variant, etc.), and allowing for progressive disclosure of complexity. We have a *lot* of things that can be tweaked and complicated, but with relatively simple minimal requirements. We want to make both possible. Could you link to some reference covering variable-length arrays in XML? I know about VLAs in C and such, but I can't anything XML related by that name